# How to replace ibus with whatever used to work in 12.04?

Tags: 14.10, gnome-classic, ibus

Upgraded from 12.04 to 14.10, as usual, bunch of problems.
One of the problems is ibus which is not working properly, example is here (no answers) https://askubuntu.com/questions/546307/allow-different-input-sources-per-window-is-broken-in-ubuntu-14-10-gnome-sessi

So I want to downgrade it to whatever used to work in 12.04 (setxkbmap?)
If I just remove ibus* packages and configure setxkbmap, it still doesn't work as expected: layout per window does not work, and lauout icon is missing.

What is the proper way of replacing ibus with something more stable?